# Apache HTTP client - still not usable from GAE/J

Tags: google-app-engine

Hoped that this has been resolved with the recently announced outbound socket API, but that's not the case - here is the error when trying to establish HTTP connection:

> INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Operation failure: setSocketOptions: Not yet implemented

from the official documentation Google state that:

> You cannot use most getsockopt/setsockopt calls.

question is, has anyone knows how to workaround for now? urlfetch is not an option, I want to establish SSL connection with client side certificate, urlfetch doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want HttpClient to run on AppEngine, try this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(new AppEngineClientConnectionManager());
```

with the following custom `ClientConnectionManager` that doesn't set any socket opions.

Tested with HttpClient 4.2.5 and a simple `HttpGet` on AppEngine 1.8.1 -- you might need to override/reconfigure more, depending on your usage of HttpClient:

```
class AppEngineClientConnectionManager extends BasicClientConnectionManager {    
  @Override
  protected ClientConnectionOperator createConnectionOperator(SchemeRegistry schreg) {
    return new DefaultClientConnectionOperator(schreg) {
      @Override
      protected void prepareSocket(Socket sock, HttpContext context, HttpParams params)
          throws IOException {
        // Don't set any socket options.
      }
    };
  }
}
```